# Pfsense OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: openvpn

I have pfsense openVPN tunnel problem. I have 10 sites. The problem is that sometime some of the sites automatically go down, so I need to restart the openVPN service in client side to resolve the problem. Could you please tell me what should I do?

note: I have unstable WAN link.

There are logs:

openvpn[20891]: Re-using SSL/TLS contex

openvpn[20891]: UDPv4 link local (bound):[AF_INET]10.99.62.18

openvpn[20891]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]10.89.57.5:1194

openvpn[20891]: [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting

openvpn[20891]: SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting

openvpn[20891]: WARNING: NO server certificate verification method has been enable.

openvpn[20891]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts

openvpn[20891]: Re-using SSL/TLS contex

openvpn[20891]: UDPv4 link local (bound):[AF_INET]10.99.62.18

openvpn[20891]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]10.89.57.5:1194

openvpn[20891]: [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting

openvpn[20891]: SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting

openvpn[20891]: WARNING: NO server certificate verification method has been enable. See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more information.

openvpn[20891]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts

openvpn[20891]: Re-using SSL/TLS contex

openvpn[20891]: UDPv4 link local (bound):[AF_INET]10.99.62.18

openvpn[20891]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]10.89.57.5:1194

openvpn[20891]: [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting

openvpn[20891]: SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting

openvpn[20891]: WARNING: NO server certificate verification method has been enable.

openvpn[20891]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts

openvpn[20891]: Re-using SSL/TLS contex

openvpn[20891]: Preseving previous TUN/TAP instance:ovpnc1

openvpn[20891]: Initialization Sequence Completed

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: Option error: route parameter netmask '255.255.240' must be an IP address

openvpn[20891]: OpenVPN ROUTE: cannot add more than 100 routes -- please increase the max-routes option in the client configuration file

openvpn[20891]: Exiting

openvpn[20891]: /usr/local/sbin/ovpn-linkdown ovpnc1 1500 1557 10.0.8.22 10.0.8.21 init

Comment: Fixing the typos in your configuration would be a good place to start.

Comment: Could you please explain me more?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't provide any log messages to help us diagnose what's going on, so the best I can do is to recommend that you enable SSH access to each remote site (using key auth only of course) so that you can ssh into them and reconnect the tunnel as needed.

Comment: I will show you the log. I use SSH now to resolve my problem, but I would like to know what is the exact problem to troubleshoot in true way. Thank you.